# Combining paste() and expression() functions in plot labels

Tags: r, plot

Consider this simple example:

```
labNames <- c('xLab','yLabl')
plot(c(1:10),xlab=expression(paste(labName[1], x^2)),ylab=expression(paste(labName[2], y^2)))
```

What I want is for the character entry defined by the variable 'labName,
 'xLab' or 'yLab' to appear next to the X^2 or y^2 defined by the expression(). As it is, the actual text 'labName' with a subscript is joined to the superscripted expression.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

An alternative solution to that of @Aaron is the `bquote()` function. We need to supply a valid R expression, in this case `LABEL ~ x^2` for example, where `LABEL` is the string you want to assign from the vector `labNames`. `bquote` evaluates R code within the expression wrapped in `.( )` and subsitutes the result into the expression.

Here is an example:

```
labNames <- c('xLab','yLab')
xlab <- bquote(.(labNames[1]) ~ x^2)
ylab <- bquote(.(labNames[2]) ~ y^2)
plot(c(1:10), xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab)
```

(Note the `~` just adds a bit of spacing, if you don't want the space, replace it with `*` and the two parts of the expression will be juxtaposed.)

Comment: More examples: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2018/03/math-notation-for-r-plot-titles-expression-and-bquote/

Comment: wondering why this answer was selected/got more upvotes than the substitute solution? I thought more people would be familiar with substitute than bquote

Comment: @timing I don't know, but I find the `bquote()` syntax less verbose and it allows you to work with expressions, not strings

Comment: This works, except that I want an equal `=` sign in my expression, like `R^2 = my.variable.evaluated` and the `=` causes an error. Any suggestions? edit: SOVLED- use `==` instead!

Answer (score 40):

EDIT: added a new example for ggplot2 at the end

See **?plotmath** for the different mathematical operations in R

You should be able to use expression without paste. If you use the tilda (~) symbol within the expression function it will assume there is a space between the characters, or you could use the * symbol and it won't put a space between the arguments

Sometimes you will need to change the margins in you're putting superscripts on the y-axis.

```
par(mar=c(5, 4.3, 4, 2) + 0.1)
plot(1:10, xlab = expression(xLab ~ x^2 ~ m^-2),
     ylab = expression(yLab ~ y^2 ~ m^-2),
     main="Plot 1")
```

[image]

```
plot(1:10, xlab = expression(xLab * x^2 * m^-2),
     ylab = expression(yLab * y^2 * m^-2),
     main="Plot 2")
```

[image]

```
plot(1:10, xlab = expression(xLab ~ x^2 * m^-2),
     ylab = expression(yLab ~ y^2 * m^-2),
     main="Plot 3")
```

[image]

Hopefully you can see the differences between plots 1, 2 and 3 with the different uses of the ~ and * symbols. An extra note, you can use other symbols such as plotting the degree symbol for temperatures for or mu, phi. If you want to add a subscript use the square brackets.

```
plot(1:10, xlab = expression('Your x label' ~ mu[3] * phi),
     ylab = expression("Temperature (" * degree * C *")"))
```

[image]

Here is a ggplot example using expression with a nonsense example

```
require(ggplot2)
```

Or if you have the pacman library installed you can use p_load to automatically download and load and attach add-on packages

```
# require(pacman)
# p_load(ggplot2)

data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10)

ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + 
  xlab(expression(bar(yourUnits) ~ g ~ m^-2 ~ OR ~ integral(f(x)*dx, a,b))) + 
  ylab(expression("Biomass (g per" ~ m^3 *")")) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I've started using ggplot as my main plotting tool and this method works for ggplot as well

Comment: while a nicely elaborated example of matplotlib, this answer doesn't actually allow for substition of values from a character vector into the axes. The intro of your example gave me the idea it would be helpful for ggplot, but other answers here are more helpful.

Comment: To be honest I don't quite see how this answers the OP question, which is how you can `paste` a variable value inside an `expression`. In these examples the value is written by hand. This way doesn't work if, say, you have to produce 100 plots with different values through a `for`-loop.

Answer (score 37):

Use `substitute` instead.

```
labNames <- c('xLab','yLab')
plot(c(1:10),
     xlab=substitute(paste(nn, x^2), list(nn=labNames[1])),
     ylab=substitute(paste(nn, y^2), list(nn=labNames[2])))
```

Answer (score 12):

Very nice example using paste and substitute to typeset both symbols (mathplot) and variables at http://vis.supstat.com/2013/04/mathematical-annotation-in-r/

Here is a ggplot adaptation

```
library(ggplot2)
x_mean <- 1.5
x_sd <- 1.2
N <- 500

n <- ggplot(data.frame(x <- rnorm(N, x_mean, x_sd)),aes(x=x)) +
    geom_bar() + stat_bin() +
    labs(title=substitute(paste(
             "Histogram of random data with ",
             mu,"=",m,", ",
             sigma^2,"=",s2,", ",
             "draws = ", numdraws,", ",
             bar(x),"=",xbar,", ",
             s^2,"=",sde),
             list(m=x_mean,xbar=mean(x),s2=x_sd^2,sde=var(x),numdraws=N)))

print(n)
```

Comment: Nice. This is insane, but it's the only approach I was able to get to work! Here an example combining unicode symbols with expression! ``title = substitute(paste("n = ", n, ",  ", bar(x), " = ", mu, ",  ", "\u03C3/\u221An = ", se), 
    list(n = df[["n"]], mu = format(df[["mu"]], digits = 2, nsmall = 2), se = format(df[["se"]], digits = 2, nsmall = 2), sep = ""))``, where ``df`` is a dataframe holding the values to be printed (the sample size ``n``, the sample mean ``mu``and the standard error ``se``). Wow.

Comment: This is also the only solution for ggplot that I could get to work. Note for people like me that routinely use `paste0` over `paste`, use of `paste` is essential here.

Answer (score 6):

If x^2 and y^2 were expressions already given in the variable squared, this solves the problem:

```
labNames <- c('xLab','yLab')
squared <- c(expression('x'^2), expression('y'^2))

xlab <- eval(bquote(expression(.(labNames[1]) ~ .(squared[1][[1]]))))
ylab <- eval(bquote(expression(.(labNames[2]) ~ .(squared[2][[1]]))))

plot(c(1:10), xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab)
```

Please note the [[1]] behind squared[1]. It gives you the content of "expression(...)" between the brackets without any escape characters.