# How to paste a variable name into R `plot`

Tags: r

This seems like it should be pretty obvious, but I've tried [`substitute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973898/combining-paste-and-expression-functions-in-plot-labels), [`bquote`](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-plot-an-expression-label-with-variable-text-td2341465.html), `expression`, `paste`, and `cat`, with similar results (failure).

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols("SAM")
thing = "SAM"
plot(SAM)      #this works fine
plot(thing)    #this does not
```

Encasing `thing` in `xts(thing)` and so on doesn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
plot(get(thing))
```

Running `thing = "SAM"` simply assigns the character "SAM" to a variable named `thing`. R has no way to know (without you telling it) that you want it to connect the *value* of the character vector `thing` to a particular object in the environment (i.e. `SAM`). So `get` does the trick here.

Comment: Addendum: I'm actually trying to `plot(SAM[,6])` but I thought the way I asked the question would be simpler. I tried `plot(get(cat(thing` and `plot(cat(get(thing` concatenated with `"[,6]", sep="")))` -- but neither that nor setting `thing = "SAM[,6]"` and `plot(get(thing))` works. (`plot(SAM[,6]` works.)

Comment: @Jack Maney I wasn't allowed to accept right away (there's a time limit on the checkmark button).

Comment: @LaoTzu I think maybe what you want, then, is `plot(get(thing)[,6])`. `get` retrieves the object, _then_ you can apply `[` subsetting.

Comment: And note that you can replace the 6 with the character `"SAM.Adjusted"` if you like.

Comment: Thanks again! That was right too. I don't even want to think about how to get `SAM.adjusted` to wear a variable value after so much work, so I'll stick with the `[,6]` -- that's the same for all `quantmod` tickers.

Comment: You can also use the `Ad` function in quantmod to get the `SAM.adjusted` column.