# Add values and superscript to pie-labels

Tags: r

I'm struggling with adding a superscript to the labels of a plot. 
I would like to have the '3' in the labels (..m^3) as superscript. I tried expression(), substitute() etc. but didn't find the correct solution.

```
values <- c(2, 4, 5)
pie(values, labels = paste(values, "m^3") )
```

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit cumbersome workaround:

```
foo <- sapply(as.list(values), function(x) bquote(.(x) ~ m^3))
pie(values, labels = as.expression(foo))
```

Comment: Ha, I found the thread where I've discovered `bquote` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973898/combining-paste-and-expression-functions-in-plot-labels