# R plot: Using italics and a variable in a title

Tags: r, plot

Using R 2.14.0 with windows 7, I want to include italics and a changing variable in my title using R plot().  Here's some code:

```
ps=c(1,2,3)

layout(matrix(1:3,1,3))

#this works but isn't what I want
for(i in 1:3){
    plot(1,1,main=expression(paste(italic(p),'=5')))
}
#this doesn't work
for(i in 1:3){
    plot(1,1,main=expression(paste(italic(p),'=',ps[i])))
}
#this doesn't work either
for(i in 1:3){
    plot(1,1,main=paste(expression(paste(italic(p),'=')),ps[i]))
}
```

What I want in the title is p[in italics]=the value of ps during that iteration.  For instance for the first iteration, "*p*=0.1"

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this help?

```
ps=c(1,2,3)
layout(matrix(1:3,1,3))
for(i in 1:3){
    plot(1,1,main=substitute(paste(italic(p), " = 0.", x, sep=""), list(x=ps[i])))
}
```

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973898/combining-paste-and-expression-functions-in-plot-labels) this question.

Comment: The sep argument to plotmath `paste` is not needed. And a simple method would dispense with `paste` and the hokey "0." and just use bquote: main=bquote( italic(p)==.(ps[i]/10) )