# Using italics in the title on an object from a dataframe

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, paste, italic

I want to plot names that come from a dataframe in italic as a ylab. 
The solution at [R plot: Using italics and a variable in a title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707857/r-plot-using-italics-and-a-variable-in-a-title) does not work in this case.
Using `substitute` or `expression` R literally reads my code

e.g. `substitute (paste 'Species = ', italic (rownames (genR) [i]))`

will come out in the test as:

Species = *rownames (genR)[1]*

and I wanted

Species = *Musa paradisiaca*

Any advice?

Many thanks!

Comment: Should have been: `substitute( paste ('Species = ', italic (val) ), list(val = rownames (genR) [i]) )`. If you don't give `substitute` a value to substitute, it can't do anything.

Comment: It really was a duplicate. You just didn't apply the answer as it was illustrated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `bquote`

```
 nm1 <- 'Musa paradisiaca'
 plot(1,1, main=bquote('Species = '~italic(.(nm1))))
```

[image]

#### Update

Or using `substitute`

```
 plot(1,1, main=eval(substitute(expr=expression(paste('Species = ',
                              italic(x))), env=list(x=as.name(nm1)))))
```