# Substitute not displaying text on plots

Tags: r, osx-mountain-lion, plotmath

I just recently learnt about `plotmath` and its ability to put mathematical expression in text on plots.

However I'm encountering some strange behaviour where the `substitute` function does not render any text.

Here's a simple case that should work (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4974521/2341679)):

```
labNames <- c('xLab','yLab')
plot(c(1:10),
     xlab=substitute(paste(nn, x^2), list(nn=labNames[1])),
     ylab=substitute(paste(nn, y^2), list(nn=labNames[2])))
```

When I run this code snippet, there is no xlab or ylab text.

I'm running mac osx and R 3.0.0. This problem persists whether i output to Quartz or to a png file.

Here's my sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin12.3.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Works for me...(on windows).

Comment: Problem persists when i use `bquote` as well. However i can get text to render using `plotmath` if I do not try to substitute any values in.

Comment: It works as expected on a linux server i have access to.

Comment: i suspect `Quartz` is the culprit.

Comment: Works for me as well (Windows R version 3.0.2)

Comment: Works for me if I do `R --no-init-file` Currently tracking down the culprit in my `.Rprofile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit: there was a weird interaction with an `option` in my `.Rprofile`

The following line causes the issue if i don't load the `devtools` package:

`options(devtools.desc.author="'Scott Ritchie <sritchie73@gmail.com> [aut, cre]'")`

Strangely, there doesn't seem to be an issue if i define other irrelevant options (`options(notanoption=TRUE)` caused no issues).