# Parse superscript in discrete axis values on geom_bar

Tags: r, parsing, ggplot2, geom-bar, superscript

I'm trying to add a superscript to some x-axis values in order to connect to a footnote that'll be at the bottom of the page. The easy workaround would just be an asterisk instead of `^a` but that won't work for my purposes.

I did a lot of searching and while there's plenty of posts about superscripts in axis labels, I couldn't find any about superscripts in axis values. Most of them appeared to centera round adding a `gg + labs(x = expression("blah^a"))`.

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393750/superscripts-in-heat-plot-labels-in-ggplot-r) post about parsing superscripts inside a `geom_text()` but it appears the same doesn't work for a `geom_bar()`.

Here's some test data:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = c("alpha", "bravo^a"),
                  y = c(10, 8))

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = x, 
               y = y),
           stat = "identity")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to `parse` the text inside `scale_x_discrete`

Edit: add `geom_text` example

```r
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(x = c("alpha", "bravo^a"),
                  y = c(10, 8))

### need to convert x to factor if R >= 4.0
dat$x <- factor(dat$x)

ggplot(data = dat) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = x, 
               y = y),
           stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = parse(text = levels(dat$x))) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = y,
                label = x), 
            parse = TRUE, 
            nudge_y = 1,
            size = 5) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: On R version >= 4, you need to convert `dat$x` to a factor for this to work