# Combining paste() and expression() in plot tick mark labels

Tags: r, plot, expression

Consider this example:

```
labs <- c("AT~frac(T,C)~G","GGAA","TTAA","AAAA")
plot(c(1:4), c(1:4), axes=F, xlab="",ylab="", par(mar=c(8,3,2,1)))
axis(1, at=c(1:4), labels=labs, las=2)
```

that generates this:

[image]

My intention is to have something like this:

[image]

that I hardcoded as:

```
plot(c(1:4), c(1:4), type="n", axes=F, xlab="",ylab="")
axis(1, at=c(1:4), labels=c(expression(AT~frac(T,C)~G), expression(GGAA), expression(TTAA), expression(AAAA)), las=2)
```

The closest answer I got was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4973898/5465885).
Getting `expression()` to work as I desired is really very confusing for me. I intend to have these x-axis tick mark labels dynamically generated from available data using a vector of "expression strings".

Comment: did my answer solve your issue or do you still struggle?

Answer (score 3):

You were close! `frac()` is a function that you need to call. it can be used with strings as an argument. This sample

```
labs <- expression(paste("AT"~frac("T","C")~"G",sep=""),"GGAA","TTAA","AAAA")
plot(c(1:4), c(1:4), axes=F, xlab="",ylab="")
axis(1, at=c(1:4), labels=labs, las=2)
```

generates this plot:

[image: labels]